# What happens if we lost, sell, or drop quest item in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

For example, I have this item called "purchase" agreement.

Say I drop it.

Then what? I can't complete the quests?

Answer (score 11):

You can't lose, sell, or drop quest items, so your concern is a non-issue.

Comment: I should have experimented. Yap it says quest items cannot be removed from inventory

Comment: i should note that there is a method to remove quest items but then they can no longer be used. i use a House Mod which adds a place outside Whiterun and inside this house is a place where you can put the Elder Scrolls which can't be removed unless you sold them in Winterhold. i stored the one you use in getting Dragonrend but then when i needed it for the Dawnguard main questsline when i went to pick it up the quest didn't recognize it requiring me to buy it back in Winterhold as if i had sold it there (as per the dialog i got). of cause this was a mod so who knows what they did

Answer (score 1):

No, Quest Items can't be dropped.